# VSCode - Line Select Down

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know I can use **Column Select Down** using `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Down` or `Alt+Shift+Mouse-Drag`.

However, my problem is I want to select wordwrapped lines.

[image]

In the following picture, you can see, when selecting columns it also puts cursor in between line. I do not want that. I want the following:

[image]

How can I do that using keyboard only and keyboard-mouse combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP Here, The solution is actually very simple.

use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Mouse-Drag</kbd> to select the lines. Then press <kbd>Home</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> will place cursor only at the beginning of the selected lines. Then you can move the cursor with the <kbd>arrow</kbd> if needed.